# How to correctly get a JavaScript SP.Web object's ID and URL before loading

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

I was working on a project where I needed to get the current web's ID or URL (sometype of unique identifier) in javascript without making an service call (executeQueryAsync).  I didn't seem to be able to find a method that would return this information before a load and executeQueryAsync.  Through IE dev tools I was able to find the value of the url and the ID in the object but it was stored in some strang variables ($0_0.$1P_0 and $0_0.$r_0[0].$M_1).  Does anyone know of a supported way to get this information before the web object is loaded through the executeQueryAsync.  Here's some code to refer to, I basically don't want to perform the extra service call for this website if I've already done it once in this session for this website.

```
function DoStuff() {
    if ( GetCookie("MyStuff"+SP.ClientContext.get_current().get_web().$0_0.$1P_0) ) return;

    var listTitle = "Stuff";

    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    this.web = context.get_web();
    this.user = web.get_currentUser();
    this.list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Author' /><Value Type='Integer'><UserID /></Value></Eq></Where></Query><RowLimit>1</RowLimit></View>");
    this.listItems = list.getItems(camlQuery);

    context.load(web);
    context.load(user);
    context.load(list);
    context.load(listItems);

    context.executeQueryAsync(StuffSucceeded, StuffFailed);
}

function StuffSucceeded(sender, args) {
    DoSomeStuff();
    SetCookie("MyStuff" + SP.ClientContext.get_current().get_web().$0_0.$1P_0, 'True', '/');
}

function StuffFailed(sender, args) {} 

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(DoStuff, "sp.js");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the server-relative web url from anywhere in SharePoint by accessing a variable called L_Menu_BaseUrl.  If you view source on ant page in SharePoint you'll find it defined.

Comment: Thanks, I unfortunately never knew about that.  I have now found this page which has a few more listed:  http://ruudheemskerk.net/archive/2010/08/03/helpful-sharepoint-javascript-functions.aspx

Comment: L_Menu_BaseUrl is also available for SharePoint 2013. That's great and thousands of thanks to Derek Gusoff!

Answer (score 5):

For SharePoint 2010 I'd recommend using `_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl`

Comment: Sometimes _spPageContextInfo is null. I found `L_Menu_BaseUrl` to be safer or even `var context = new SP.ClientContext();
    var relativeWebUrl = context.get_url();`